# 3ds max c++ plugin infinite loop

Tags: c++, 3dsmax

What's the best way to have a plugin with an infinite loop in order to watch something or doing stuff forever?

### Update

A concurrent thread seems working...

Comment: I don't see how this question is relevant when you haven't indicated you have done any work on this subject. What have you tried?

Comment: Let the purpose of a plugin be doing some job repeatedly forever. How do you do it? A ```while true``` loop causes 3ds max to crash.

Comment: As former developer on max, there is enough in the SDK to be able to do just about anything without having to resort to a while true loop to do work.

Comment: That's exactly what I believe and am looking for. There must be a main loop.

Comment: Keep in mind just what thread your 'infinite loop' is running in. 3dsmax runs the UI through the main thread. So you MUST NOT run your infinite loop on that thread. In the end, I'd just forget about the infinite loop idea, it's just a bad one.

Comment: You're right. The infinite loop MUST be on another thread. About forgetting it, I found no alternative.